# Can I make a custom MSI that includes Vagrant, VirtualBox and other dependencies?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, vagrant, virtualbox, package-managers

**Summary:** I want to figure out a way to automate the installation of a project and it's dependencies onto the Windows(7, 8) platform. In particular I want to install all the dependencies required to "vagrant up", and I want to distribute this to my team members.

---

**Problems:** I have considered using a freeware tool ( http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ ) to help me create an MSI. However i think vagrant is now only available to download with specialized MSI installers. see http://mitchellh.com/abandoning-rubygems

In addition to needing vagrant, I want to automate the installation of oracle virtualbox, and we need a few vagrant plugins.

I also want to include the project itself.I have a vagrantfile that has been tested and works well.

---

**Restatment of the problem:**
In other words, since Vagrant appears to provide only MSI installers for Windows, I don't know if it is still possible to create a custom msi that includes the other items I want. If it were possible I don't know how to do it. If there is a better way than using MSI, pease tell.

Answer (score 1):

A Windows Installer package is not meant to be a recursive structure.

Try a WiX's Bootstrapper project to create an EXE with chained sub-installers. It uses the WiX burn engine, which is a bootstrapper, downloader (optional), bundler (optional embedding), chainer, reboot manager, package manager.

Comment: This looks like an appropriate tool. I find the learning curve a bit intimidating, but the tutorial ( http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial ) helps.  Does WIX burn engine act like apt-get, in that it can download vagrant and virtualbox from remote repositories, or do I need to install those programs locally and compile them from source to place them in sub-installers?

Comment: You need to create an ExePackage for VirtualBox and an MsiPackage for Vagrant. In each, you can put a DownloadUrl. WiX creates two types of things: Windows Installer packages and patches, and WiX burn bootstrappers. They are functionally separate but use similar syntaxed and the same build tools. So, be sure you are looking at the right documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Advanced Installer (as you mentioned) you can add Vagrant, VirtualBox and the other dependencies in the "Prerequisites" page to as described in their tutorials:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#prerequisites

You can automate their installation by setting command lines for them.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using something like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)?

I've used it before to create BAT scripts to do the installation of Virtual Box and Vagrant on Windows 7.

Something like the following could be a place to start:

```
@echo off

if not exist C:\Chocolatey goto InstallChocolatey
echo Chocolatey already installed.
goto:InstallPrograms

:InstallChocolatey
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin

:InstallPrograms
call cinst chocolatey
call cinst virtualbox
call cinst vagrant
```